# Skyrim letter bug

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I recently recieved a letter from a courier in Winterhold, but I don't know who sent it. The letter is labeled "Letter from [...]". This is what it says, "Shadth Gra-Dulamakh,
You may or may not realize this, but by taking care of [...], you have indirectly helped me. Don't worry about how I know it was you, I won't be informing the authorities. But I would like to reward you for your efforts.

Please visit me at your earliest convenience.

- - [...]" Unfortunately I couldn't provide a picture. Has anyone else run into this problem, and if so, is there a way to fix it?

Comment: What exactly is this picture? Can you give a description about it?

Answer (score 4):

It's not a big issue.

This letter is a generic dynamically generated quest based on two NPCs.  The [...] is suppose to be another NPC's name, but something weird happened with the script and it couldn't pick up the NPC's name.

This isn't going to break any real quests for you, you don't need to worry about it.

The second place where this can show up are inheritance letters when NPCs are killed.

Comment: Specifically, this can happen if you have a mod installed which added a character who has a relationship which would trigger the letter, but doesn't have a complete record for their name in the CK.  Mods adding large amounts of NPCs can cause this.